# Expired JWT Token when trying to authenticate?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, jwt

I am using JWT for the first time, I am finding a hard time to understand the way it works fully, every time I find a solution to simethong, an other thing pops out.

I was trying to authenticate before and when I send the correct username and password I get a token when using Postman.

I left the project few hours and came back and now when I try to authenticate I get this error :

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Expired JWT Token"
}
```

I don't know how to solve it, because I did not knwo I may face such problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using an API and I understand correctly then this is self-explanatory. Your token has expired, which JWT's usually do after an hour of their `iat`. You'll need to re-generate a new token and request using that.

Comment: Yes, your token is expired, and you need to get a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes like this:

You make first api request, pass your credentials, get token and store it somewhere.

After that you should pass that token (trough "Bearer" header field) with every other request so server could identify you.

But that token won't be valid forever. After some time (TTL) it will expire and you'll get message like that. Then you have to repeat authentication to get new token.

So just repeat request you made at start, pass again credentials, collect and store again new token and keep using it as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle`, you can set the `TimeToLive` for JWT in `lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml` in config/packages.

The `token_ttl:` attribute is for setting up the `TimeToLive` of a token in seconds (e.g., 604800 is equal to 7 days).